# How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My version of node is always v0.6.1-pre even after I install brew node and NVM install v0.6.19.

My node version is:

```
node -v
v0.6.1-pre
```

NVM says this (after I install a version of node for the first time in one bash terminal):

```
nvm ls
v0.6.19
current:    v0.6.19
```

But when I restart bash, this is what I see:

```
nvm ls
v0.6.19
current:    v0.6.1-pre
default -> 0.6.19 (-> v0.6.19)
```

So where is this phantom node 0.6.1-pre version and how can I get rid of it? I'm trying to install libraries via NPM so that I can work on a project.

I tried using BREW to update before NVM, using `brew update` and `brew install node`. 
I've tried deleting the "node" directory in my `/usr/local/include` and the "node" and "node_modules" in my `/usr/local/lib`.
I've tried uninstalling npm and reinstalling it following [these](https://superuser.com/questions/268946/uninstall-node-js) instructions.

All of this because I was trying to update an older version of node to install the "zipstream" library. Now there's folders in my users directory, and the node version STILL isn't up to date, even though NVM says it's using 0.6.19.

**Ideally, I'd like to uninstall nodejs, npm, and nvm, and just reinstall the entire thing from scratch on my system.**

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7371#issuecomment-341530174 and https://gist.github.com/dotcomputercraft/b7283bd52f4b5389e748 and http://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/

Comment: /usr/bin/node is another one...

Comment: this might help for whoever installed node via pkg file. https://superuser.com/questions/36567/how-do-i-uninstall-any-apple-pkg-package-file

Comment: Mac 10.13.5 has got /Users/myusername/node_modules should I delete this folder as well ? I searched in this thread but nobody faced this issue it seems

Comment: @Pacerier even after following instruction in gist, still node and npm exists on Mac OS 10.13.5

Comment: Old question, but this seems like an XY problem: The whole point of NVM is to use different Node versions on the same machine.

Answer (score 2006, accepted):

Apparently, there was a `/Users/myusername/local` folder that contained a `include` with `node` and `lib` with `node` and `node_modules`. How and why this was created instead of in my `/usr/local` folder, I do not know.

Deleting these local references fixed the phantom v0.6.1-pre. If anyone has an explanation, I'll choose that as the correct answer.

**EDIT:**

You may need to do the additional instructions as well:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
```

which is the equivalent of (same as above)...

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp
```

or (same as above) broken down...

To completely uninstall node + npm is to do the following:

1. go to **/usr/local/lib** and delete any **node** and **node_modules**
2. go to **/usr/local/include** and delete any **node** and **node_modules** directory
3. if you installed with **brew install node**, then run **brew uninstall node** in your terminal
4. check your Home directory for any **local** or **lib** or **include** folders, and delete any **node** or **node_modules** from there
5. go to **/usr/local/bin** and delete any **node** executable

You may also need to do:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
```

Additionally, NVM modifies the PATH variable in `$HOME/.bashrc`, which must be [reverted manually](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#removal).

Then download **nvm** and follow the instructions to install node. The latest versions of node come with **npm**, I believe, but you can also reinstall that as well.

Comment: Worked for me, too. Thank you! Had to run the node installer though. `n` and `nvm` both did not work for me on first try.

Comment: I'm attempting to follow these steps but Terminal spits out "permission denied" and tells me the directory is not empty. Any ideas?

Comment: I also had to `rm -rf /Users/[homedir]/.npm`.

Comment: Also needed to remove `/Users/[homedir]/.nvm`

Comment: Include folders are where `c` headers are stored.

Comment: I also ran `brew doctor` and then `brew prune` to clean up a bunch of broken symlinks for NPM.

Comment: I threw together a script that I've now battle tested. Thanks @DominicTancredi this works great! https://gist.github.com/brock/5b1b70590e1171c4ab54

Comment: I also had to add: `sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp`. I had added it with MacPorts before I switched to brew.

Comment: Probably want to run `brew uninstall --force node` to make sure that it removes *all* versions of Node in Homebrew.

Comment: I was dumb enough to install node packages as sudo, so I also had to `sudo rm -rf /root/.npm`.

Comment: Thank you for this post! I also had some additional permission issues and had to run `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local` to get brew to install node.

Comment: On Ubuntu, the paths do not include `\local`.

Comment: Also remove `sudo rm -rf ~/.node` and `sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp`

Comment: Also check if which node is - /Users/xyz/var/bin/node
Then delete from here also.

Comment: Additionally remove: `/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp`

Comment: The two commands don't seem to delete `/usr/local/include/node/`, but the summary underneath it mentions that folder. Am I misunderstanding this answer?

Comment: The two commands in your answer are not equivalent. The second one deletes `~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules`, the first does not.

Comment: Another file should be removed: ```/usr/bin/node```

Comment: There are also man pages in section 7 `/usr/local/share/man/man7/npm-*`

Comment: Also had to remove node from /usr/lib, /usr/include, and /usr/bin

Comment: Mac user. Another two commands which help me clear `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/node` `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/n/versions/node`

Comment: How does: `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp` delete `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` or `/usr/local/lib/node`? I don't see any of those folders specified in the command. (In manual deletion steps that claims to be the same as the command)

Comment: don't install node+npm on your OS directly, use a docker container https://hub.docker.com/_/node/ , this will make your life incredibly simpler when it comes to cleanup

Comment: For me I kept seeing my old version of npm after running all of the above commands. I had to restart my computer in order for npm to show the updated version. I'm on Ubuntu 64 bit.

Comment: Any time @Mehr. The community here has been extraordinary in supporting this question and answer.

Comment: Also needed to remove /Users/[homedir]/.npmrc

Comment: Mac 10.13.5 has got /Users/myusername/node_modules should I delete this folder as well ?

Comment: does this system still not have a way of uninstalling things? I mean, what century are they stuck in??

Comment: This thread demonstrates to me that NodeJs is not a professional tool; at least, not on the Mac.

Comment: Everyone should be careful when upgrading npm. There is a trap. Check https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-np before proceed or will end up cleaning it all again.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node as well

Comment: I had to remove: `/Volumes/node_modules`, `~/.npm`, and `~/.nvm` and had no node or npm binaries in `/usr/local/bin`. `~/.nvm` was referenced in `~/.bash_profile`. I ran `rm -Rf /Volumes/node_modules`, check. But `rm -Rf ~/.npm` failed with and without `sudo`, so from Terminal I did `open ~/.npm`, hit cmd-shift-. (Mojave - Finder shows dot-prefixed files), and used the UI instead (which worked!). Then `rm -Rf ~/.nvm` got “access denied”, but `sudo rm -Rf ~/.nvm` worked! Removed nvm from `~/.bash_profile`. I hope this helps someone... because this didn't follow ANY of the doco I could find.

Comment: I also had to delete /usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit

Comment: removed in addition.. 
~./npmrc
~/.npm-global ~/.npm.  /usr/local/include/node

Comment: Just a tip that I found helpful after following this: if you (after completing all the steps above) run `brew install node`, brew will complain about any previously-existing node files/dirs and will refuse to install node, failing with an error. You can then look at that error and see which existing file(s) you need to get rid of.

Comment: even this needs to be removed sudo rm /usr/bin/node

Comment: also need to delete this Directory too: "/usr/local/share/doc/node"

Comment: I used "brew cleanup" instead of  "brew prune"

Comment: I needed to remove /usr/local/Cellar/node@version

Comment: I'm sorry, this is just sad. If I could find a way around every using this cobbled-together toolset I would run away as fast as possible. This is ridiculous.

Comment: also need to rm /usr/local/bin/npx

Answer (score 697):

## **For brew users, OSX**:

To remove:

```bash
brew uninstall node; 
# or `brew uninstall --force node` which removes all versions
brew cleanup;
rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
rm -rf ~/.npm;
```

To install:

```bash
brew install node;
which node # => /usr/local/bin/node
export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules' # <--- add this ~/.bashrc
```

You can run `brew info node` for more details regarding your node installs.

---

## consider using NVM instead of brew

NVM (node version manager) is a portable solution for managing multiple versions of node

### https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

```
> nvm uninstall v4.1.0
> nvm install v8.1.2
> nvm use v8.1.2
> nvm list
         v4.2.0
         v5.8.0
        v6.11.0
->       v8.1.2
         system
```

[you can use this with AVN](https://github.com/wbyoung/avn) to automatically switch versions as you hop between different projects with different node dependencies.

Comment: How to set env vars so that node and npm are available after such install?

Comment: You may need to run brew with the `--force` flag to make sure all versions of node are removed: 

`$ brew uninstall --force node`

Comment: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory` what can I do now?

Comment: try `which npm`, its possible it got installed somewhere else? if it did get installed somewhere else, youll need to make sure the folder is in your $PATH

Comment: I am wondering why you are using semicolons at the end of your bash commands in the terminal.

Comment: i've had trouble in the past copying to clipboard and having line breaks removed on paste. this just ensures the commands are captured as as separate ideas regardless, but they aren't by any means necessary.

Comment: Mac 10.13.5 has got /Users/myusername/node_modules should I delete this folder as well ? I searched in this thread but nobody faced this issue it seems

Comment: yes, you can usually safely remove`~/node_modules` or any node_modules folder for that matter. it will be created or re-generated (if you need it) when you run `npm install`

Comment: when I try to uninstall using brew and --force I get `Error: Could not remove /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.1.0! Check its permissions` what next?

Comment: hi alex - this sounds like a separate issue. have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions

Comment: ```nvm install 11.13.0``` and ```nvm use 11.13.0```

Comment: > "consider using NVM instead of brew";  

Ironically you can install NVM **with** brew!;  

Great tip, thanks.

Comment: Using NVM helped.

Comment: As recommendation nowadays try use ASDF instead of NVM

Comment: Finally found a solution with 
nvm deactivate
nvm uninstall <version>

Comment: After ```running brew uninstall --force node``` && ```brew cleanup```, ```node --version``` and ```npm version``` are still returning a version

Comment: you can use `which node` to determine the location of these binaries, perhaps you installed them with different tooling

Answer (score 215):

## UPDATE: 23 SEP 2016 - Intel Macs 10.11.x and above

#### If you're afraid of running these commands...

Thanks to [jguix](https://gist.github.com/jguix) for [this quick tutorial](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef#gistcomment-1880118).

**First, create an intermediate file:**

```
lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom >> ~/filelist.txt
```

**Manually review your file (located in your home `~` folder)**

```
 ~/filelist.txt
```

**Then delete the files:**

```
cat ~/filelist.txt | while read f; do sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
```

---

## Intel Macs 10.10.x and below

**Thanks [Lenar Hoyt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852592/lenar-hoyt)**

**Gist Comment Source:** [gistcomment-1572198](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef#gistcomment-1572198)

**Original Gist:** [TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef#file-gistfile1-txt)

```
lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom | while read f; do sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
```

---

## ORIGINAL: 7 JUL 2014

I know this post is a little dated but just wanted to share the commands that worked for me in Terminal when removing Node.js.

```
lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom | while read f; do  sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done
 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
```

Comment: Whoa-- this is terrifying. At least the first "rm" isn't a "rm -rf", which, if there's a blank line on the outpur of sbom, would remove all of /usr/local. Before doing anything so heavyhanded, scrutinize the sbom output and where all these dirs came from and make sure you know exactly what you're removing.

Comment: I should add... if you've got a healthy self-preservation instinct, it should be extremely difficult for you to type or copy-paste that second command, which begins with "sudo rm -rf /", at all.   One sneeze, or the cat jumps on your keyboard, and you've destroyed your filesystem.

Comment: Now you've added s second place too ;)

Comment: I apologize if my approach is rather "aggressive" in some respects, however, I guess I'm rather comfortable and know my way around Terminal? It's always important to scrutinize every command you send for one typo can--LITERALLY--cost everything.  The only reason why I shared these commands was mostly because I hoped people would just copy & paste instead of (what feels like) talk down on it.

Comment: It’s `org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom` instead of `org.nodejs.pkg.bom`.

Comment: This still works in 2017 for uninstalling Node.js v7.7.

Comment: @DonHatch copy the line without the first letter so it starts with `udo..` and then prepend `s` before running it.

Comment: The lsbom command outputs relative paths so the script was trying to delete paths that looked like `/usr/local/./node/yada`. To remove the `./` prefix I used cut filter:

`lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom | cut -c 3- | while read f; do sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done`

Comment: Another way to get around the `./` prefix is to `cd /` before running the `lsbom` command.

Answer (score 203):

https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/

Run following commands to remove node completely from system in MACOS

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm ~/.nvm ~/node_modules ~/.node-gyp ~/.npmrc ~/.node_repl_history
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/node-debug /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node-gyp
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /usr/local/include/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/lib/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp

brew uninstall node
brew doctor
brew cleanup --prune-prefix
```

After this I will suggest to use following command to install node using nvm (check https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm for latest version)
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash`

from https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

**Why nvm?**
this is a good question, there will be projects requiring different versions of node, 
i.e. A requires node version 12 while B requires node version 14. This version management of node is provided by nvm only.

Comment: This worked for me in May 2021, using Mac OS: 10.15.6. Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you suggesting to use nvm to install node and not brew or npm?

Comment: @SamBruton updated the answer above also because anyway. we will need nvm, so better install node using nvm only

Comment: Worked for me in November 2021, using Mac OS 11.5.2

Comment: did not worked for me, January 2022. Macos 12.0.1

Comment: what is the error you are getting @GulamHussain ?

Comment: I wanted to completely uninstall nodejs, but even after following your answer i couldn't uninstall. I got no error while running those commands but `node -v` command still shows that node 12.17.1 is installed. anyway somehow i manage to solve my issue without uninstalling the node. thanks for your followup btw.

Comment: Worked for me January 2022. MBP M1 PRO chip

Comment: Worked for me in March, 2022! This was the only working solution to completely remove all hidden Node binaries.

Comment: Working perfectly in April 2022 - Macbook Air M1

Comment: Worked May 2022 on MacBook Pro running Catalina!!

Comment: Works perfectly in July 2022 (I only tried this because of positive feedback in the comments, Thanks guys.)

Comment: Worked in Dec 2023 as well

Comment: Works perfectly as of Dec 2023 on Mac M1.

Comment: Worked for me in Feb'2023 on Macbook Pro(14.3.1 Sonoma), Thanks :)

Comment: Here we are in Feb 2024 and this is still the best answer.

Answer (score 180):

On Mavericks I install it from the node pkg (from nodejs site) and I uninstall it so I can re-install using brew. I only run 4 commands in the terminal:

1. `sudo rm -rf  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/`
2. `brew uninstall node`
3. `brew doctor`
4. `brew cleanup --prune-prefix`

If there is still a node installation, repeat step 2. After all is ok, I install using `brew install node`

Comment: 1 worked, but 2 fails.  I get "no such keg: usr/local/Cellar/node"

Comment: Yep, this is the best if you have are running Mavericks

Comment: I tried it but again getting same error Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully

Comment: Thanks, perfect except I had to add --force to brew uninstall

Comment: FYI: As of this writing - ```->brew prune
Error: Calling 'brew prune' is disabled! Use 'brew cleanup --prune-prefix' instead.```

Comment: step 2 is wrong. It should be "brew install node". If you have installed it before via pkg you can't uninstall it.

Comment: I was nearly dead after removing nvm, but only this solution saved me.

Answer (score 85):

I have summarized the existing answers and made sure Node.js is **COMPLETELY ERASED** along with NPM.

Lines to copy to terminal:

```
brew uninstall node;
which node;
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node;
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/;
brew doctor;
brew cleanup --prune-prefix;
```

Comment: I followed these steps and it seems to have worked.  I still have directories in my root folder like `.node-gyp/`, `.npm/`, `.npm-global/`, and `.nvm/`. Can I delete these or should I keep them if I plan on reinstalling node?

Comment: of all things, you probably want to delete /node-gyp/

Comment: wrt `brew uninstall node` - if you had installed explicit node versions by appending `@<vernum>` then you also have to uninstall them using the same identifiers, `node` alone will not blanket them

Comment: despite running `brew cleanup` (with and without the `--prune-prefix` param) for a couple of times, `brew doctor` always finds the same leftovers over and over again

Answer (score 39):

1. First:

   ```
   lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom | while read f; do  sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
   ```
2. To recap, the best way (I've found) to completely uninstall node + npm is to do the following:

   go to `/usr/local/lib` and delete any node and node_modules

   ```
   cd /usr/local/lib

   sudo rm -rf node*
   ```
3. go to `/usr/local/include` and delete any node and node_modules directory

   ```
   cd /usr/local/include

   sudo rm -rf node*
   ```
4. if you installed with `brew install node`, then run `brew uninstall node` in your terminal

   ```
   brew uninstall node
   ```
5. check your Home directory for any "local" or "lib" or "include" folders, and delete any "node" or "node_modules" from there

   go to /usr/local/bin and delete any node executable

   ```
   cd /usr/local/bin

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm

   ls -las
   ```
6. You may need to do the additional instructions as well:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d

   sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
   ```

Source: [tonyMtz](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef)

Comment: Removing `node*` is not a particularly safe way to proceed. There may be other binaries with that prefix.

Comment: Great, finally after 3 days, when every now and then there were npm issues, removed completely and reinstall using brew on my mac, works like a charm.

Comment: When fired first command getting `can't open /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom: No such file or directory
**** Can't open /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom.` Please help

Comment: Even after doing these steps on Mac 10.13.5, still I could see npm and node what may be going wrong ?

Answer (score 36):

### Complete uninstall Node.js on macOS Monterey version 12.0.1

To check the current node version installed on your system:

```
# node -v
# v14.15.0
```

Enter the given below commands to delete Node from your system:

```
# cd /usr/local/include
# sudo rm -R node
# cd ../lib
# sudo rm -R node_modules
# cd ../bin
# sudo rm -R node
```

to check that node doesn't exist anymore

```
# node -v
# -bash: node: command not found
```

### Install Node.js on macOS Monterey version 12.0.1

1. Download the LTS version of node from [the official website](https://nodejs.org/en/)

2. Double click on the **node-v16.13.1.pkg** installation package and continue with the default settings
3. Type `node -v` in your terminal to print the current installed version of node : `v16.13.1` & `npm -v` to print the current npm version installed on your machine : `8.1.2`

Comment: my `include` folder is empty

Comment: Beware: this way you'll get `EACCES: permission denied` error when you try to install anything **globally** with `npm install -g any-package-name`. The official documentation (https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) strongly recommends using Node version manager to install Node.js and npm.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked great for removing node from macOS Sonoma 14.1.2

Comment: It didn't worked on sonoma 14.3.1

Answer (score 33):

downgrade node to 0.10.36

```
  sudo npm cache clean -f
  sudo npm install -g n
  sudo n 0.10.36
```

upgrade node to stable v

```
  sudo npm cache clean -f
  sudo npm install -g n
  sudo n stable
```

Comment: I just did this and oddly, it downgraded npm from 6.4.1 to 6.2.0.

Answer (score 31):

I'm not sure if it's because I had an old version (4.4.5), or if it's because I used the official installer, but most of the files referenced in other answers didn't exist on my system. I only had to remove the following:

```
~/.node-gyp
~/.node_repl_history
/usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/npm
/usr/local/include/node
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/share/doc/node
/usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
```

I decided to keep `~/.npm` because I was planning on reinstalling Node with Homebrew.

Comment: This answer was made in 2012, so I'm sure it has some legacy-ness to it. Now, if new answers show up, I upvote them after reviewing if they're effective.

Answer (score 25):

## Complete uninstall Nodejs on macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3 (20D91)

---

### Introduction

First things first, I want to say thank you for sharing this [trick](https://gist.github.com/tonymtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef) [@tonymtz](https://github.com/tonymtz).

My system is running `macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3 (20D91)` with  `nodejs Latest Current Version: 15.14.0 (includes npm 7.7.6)` installed from the official website.

I tried to fully uninstall `nodejs` on my MacBook Pro in order to re-install it with `homebrew` package manager using:

```
lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom | while read f; do  sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done
```

but I was facing an issue like [@AhteshamShah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10684238/ahtesham-shah) mentioned in [@JohelAlvarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069262/johel-alvarez)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x#answer-31102612):

> When fired first command getting: `can't open /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom: No such file or directory **** Can't open /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom.`
> – Ahtesham Shah Jun 20 '19 at 5:09

I dived into [the original post](https://gist.github.com/tonymtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef) linked by @JohelAlvarez, reading all the comments and I've found this [comment](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef#gistcomment-1572198) from [@e2tha-e](https://github.com/e2tha-e):

> @tonymtz On my installation of Node v4.0.0 on Yosemite 10.10.5, the first line needed to be
> `lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom | while read f; do sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done`
> A different filename from `org.nodejs.pkg.bom`
> Otherwise, this worked like a charm!

@e2tha-e was right, on `macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3 (20D91`) with  `nodejs Latest Current Version: 15.14.0 (includes npm 7.7.6)` installed from official website, the file name is not `org.nodejs.pkg.bom` but `org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom` .

You can check this when you `cd /var/db/receipts/ && ls -la`.

### Solution for installation from Nodejs's official website

With your preferred Terminal, fully uninstall Nodejs from your system like this :

##### ***Option 1***

1. `lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom | while read f; do  sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done`
2. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*`

##### ***Option 2***

Go to `/var/db/receipts/` and delete any `org.nodejs.*`

1. `cd /var/db/receipts/ && ls -la`
2. `sudo rm -rf org.nodejs.*`

Go to `/usr/local/lib` and delete any `node` and `node_modules`

1. `cd /usr/local/lib && ls -la`
2. `sudo rm -rf node*`

Go to `/usr/local/include` and delete any `node` and `node_modules` directory

1. `cd /usr/local/include && ls -la`
2. `sudo rm -rf node*`

Check your `$HOME` directory for any "local" or "lib" or "include" folders, and delete any "node" or "node_modules" from there.

Go to `/usr/local/bin` and delete any node executable

1. `cd /usr/local/bin && ls -la`
2. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm`
3. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node`

You may need to do this too:

1. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1`
2. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d`
3. `sudo rm -rf ~/.npm`

After that, you can check if there is still `node` in your system with `which node` or find all occurrences for node in your system.

---

### Tips

1. Search where node files are with `find / -name 'node' | sed -E 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort -u`
2. Before running shared code by others, check your directories before to make sure you write the right file name.

Comment: Today, October 2021, the BOM for node-v17.0.0.pkg (which also supports M1) includes `./usr/local` prefixes. Hence, the `rm` command in "Option 1" does not need to add that prefix for that version.

Answer (score 22):

**Steps to Uninstall NodeJS:**

For MacOS Monterey with M1 chip, please follow the link below to uninstall node completely from the system. I have tried multiple ways but this one worked finally.

[Uninstall NodeJS & NPM from Mac M1 Monterey](https://www.positronx.io/how-to-uninstall-node-js-and-npm-from-macos/)

Additionally, please execute the following commands at the end to remove node related directories from bin folder.

```
sudo rm -R node-sass
sudo rm -R npm
sudo rm -R npx
```

To verify that node is removed:

```
node --version
```

It should say command not found.

**Steps to Install NodeJS:**

Enable Rosseta terminal on your Mac with M1 chip.
[How to enable Rosseta terminal](https://www.bigbinary.com/learn-rubyonrails-book/setting-up-mac)

Use nvm (Node Version Manager) to install NodeJS on your machine. **Why nvm??** Because you can run multiple versions of NodeJS (you can work with a new app as well as a Legacy app).

[How to install multiple versions of NodeJS using nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Create a .zshrc file if not exists.

```
touch ~/.zshrc
```

Install node using nvm.

```
nvm install node # "node" is an alias for the latest version
nvm install 14.7.0 # or 16.3.0, 12.22.1, etc
```

To verify the number of NodeJS versions available:

```
nvm ls
```

Answer (score 18):

After

```
brew uninstall node
```

I had to know which node

```
which node
```

then remove that

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
```

Answer (score 16):

- Delete node and/or node_modules from /usr/local/lib

  ```
  ex code:
  cd /usr/local/lib
  sudo rm -rf node
  sudo rm -rf node_modules
  ```
- Delete node and/or node_modules from /usr/local/include
- Delete node, node-debug, and node-gyp from /usr/local/bin
- Delete .npmrc from your home directory (these are your npm settings, don't delete this if you plan on re-installing Node right away)
- Delete .npm from your home directory
- Delete .node-gyp from your home directory
- Delete .node_repl_history from your home directory
- Delete node* from /usr/local/share/man/man1/
- Delete npm* from /usr/local/share/man/man1/
- Delete node.d from /usr/local/lib/dtrace/
- Delete node from /usr/local/opt/local/bin/
- Delete node from /usr/local/opt/local/include/
- Delete node_modules from /usr/local/opt/local/lib/
- Delete node from /usr/local/share/doc/
- Delete node.stp from /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/

Comment: I also had to remove `node@6` from `/usr/local/opt/`

Answer (score 15):

Worked for me.

```
$node --version

v11.1.0

$nvm deactivate

$nvm uninstall v11.1.0
```

Comment: But only if you have `nvm` installed.

Comment: @SebastianDressler  Yes :-) brew install nvm.  more info here https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/

Answer (score 11):

If you have already installed [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) then execute the following commands

- `nvm deactivate` - This will remove /.nvm/*/bin from $PATH
- `nvm list` - To list out all the versions of node installed in the system
- `nvm uninstall <version>` in  you can specify all the versions you want to uninstall.

It is always a good that you install node using `nvm` and uninstall using `nvm`
 rather than `brew` .

This solution worked for me.

Additional Commands

- `which node` to know the path of node installed in your system. You can rm this directory to uninstall node manually. Then you may need to adjust the PATH file accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on [Dominic Tancredi's awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/2083544), I've rolled this into a bash package and stand-alone script. If you are already using the "Back Package Manager" called [bpkg](http://bpkg.io) you can install the script by running:

```
bpkg install -g brock/node-reinstall
```

Or you can have a look at the script on Github at [brock/node-reinstall](http://github.com/brock/node-reinstall). The script allows you to re-install node using nvm or nave, and to specify a node version as your default.

Comment: I was about to post this, and see that the author himself posted the best possible answer to the problem: use node-reinstall once and you'll never look back. Got me hitting the ground running and ready for more development! Cheers for this @brockangelo!

Comment: Warning..... the `node-reinstall` script contains this line:

`sudo rm -rf $HOME/{local,lib,include,node*,npm,.npm*}`

So if you happen to independently have a directory of that name in your `$HOME` (as I do), it's going to get clobbered!

Answer (score 8):

Additional to the main answer I needed to remove all npm instances found in:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm*
```

Comment: This should be a comment on the appropriate answer, not a new answer.

Answer (score 7):

maybe you need to make

```
hash -r
```

it helps with problem of symlink

```
$ node -v
$ bash: /opt/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to download an installer package: .pkg on mac. Prefer the latest stable version.

Here is the link: [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

This package will eventually overwrite the previous version and set environment variables accordingly. Just run the installer and its done within a few clicks.

Answer (score 6):

I have been hit by an issue during uninstall of Node.js on my mac. I had some strange behavior like `npm` is still there even after having to remove it with all this.

It was because I had an old install done with macport. So you also have to uninstall it using port:

```
sudo port uninstall nodejs
```

It may have installed many different versions of Node.js so uninstall them all (one by one).

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me :-) thx for your addendum answer. Well, I started having several versions of Cordova, and one npm could not remove the one Cordova and vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

You can clone https://github.com/brock/node-reinstall and run the simple command as given in the repository.After that just restart your system.
This is the simplest method and also worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had installed Node.js from source downloaded from the git repository.  I installed with:

```
./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Because the make file supports it, I can do:

```
$ sudo make uninstall
```

Comment: How to run it parallel? say i want to run 2 versions?

Answer (score 4):

As a companion to the answers explaining cleanup and install via homebrew, I found that homebrew itself provided clear indications of the symlink clashes.

Unfortunately it provides these one by one as it encounters them, so it is a little laborious, but it does seem to find all the clashes and was the only way I could get a clean install with homebrew.

Essentially, the process is:

1. use homebrew to uninstall node
2. clean homebrew
3. use homebrew to install node and note any flagged clashing file
4. delete the flag clashing file (or whole directory if it is a 'node' directory)
5. goto step 1 until you get a clean install

[image: Diagrammatically]:

Here is a screen output from the last steps of my install - you can see it results in a clean install (eventually...):

```sc
computer1:DevResources user1$ brew install node
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/user1/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/da904f1fdab6f6b2243a810b685e67b29a642c6e945f086e0022323a37fe85f9--node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
Target /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0: 4,591 files, 54.2MB
computer1:DevResources user1$ rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'
computer1:DevResources user1$ brew uninstall node
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0... (4,591 files, 54.2MB)
computer1:DevResources user1$ brew cleanup
computer1:DevResources user1$ brew install node
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/user1/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/da904f1fdab6f6b2243a810b685e67b29a642c6e945f086e0022323a37fe85f9--node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink lib/dtrace/node.d
Target /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0: 4,591 files, 54.2MB
computer1:DevResources user1$ rm '/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d'
computer1:DevResources user1$ 
computer1:DevResources user1$ brew uninstall node
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0... (4,591 files, 54.2MB)
computer1:DevResources user1$ brew cleanup
computer1:DevResources user1$ brew install node
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/user1/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/da904f1fdab6f6b2243a810b685e67b29a642c6e945f086e0022323a37fe85f9--node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-13.1.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0: 4,591 files, 54.2MB
computer1:DevResources user1$ node -v
v13.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to deactivate node: (mac) after install new node version.

```
nvm deactivate
```

This is removed /Users/user_name/.nvm/*/bin from $PATH

And after that node was updated

```
node --version
v10.9.0
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case none of the other answers worked because I previously downgraded to node8. So instead of doing above, following worked for me:

```
which node
```

which returned `/usr/local/bin/node@8` instead of `/usr/local/bin/node`

so i executed this command:

```
brew uninstall node@8
```

which worked and then downloaded latest pkg from official site and installed. After that I had to close my terminal and start again to access new version

Answer (score 3):

@lfender6445 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919540/7390929) worked just fine for me to uninstall

Now to re-install, I had problems installing the last version instead of the most stable one, so to install a specific node version you should do:

```
brew install node@10 // 10 is the version I want
brew link node@10
```

Answer (score 3):

### Docker - alternative approach

Docker is some-kind of super-fast virtual machine which can be use to run tools like node (instead install them directly on mac-os). Advantages to do it are following

- all stuff ('milions' node files) are install inside docker image/container (they encapsulated in few inner-docker files)
- you can map your mac directory with project to your docker container and have access to node - but outside docker, mac-os sytem don't even know that node is installed. So you get some kind of 'virtual' console with available node commands which can works on real files
- you can easily kill node by find it by `docker ps` and kill by `docker rm -f name_or_num`
- you can easily uninstall docker image/containers by one command `docker rmi ...` and get free space - and install it again by run script (below)
- your node is encapsulated inside docker and don't have access to whole system - only to folders you map to it
- you can run node services and easily map they port to mac port and have access to it from web browser
- you can run many node versions at the same time
- in similar way you can install other tools like (in many versions in same time): php, databases, redis etc. - inside docker without any interaction with mac-os (which not notice such software at all). E.g. you can run at the same time 3 mysql db with different versions and 3 php application with different php version ... - so you can have many tools but clean system
- TEAM WORK: such enviroment can be easily cloned into other machines (and even to windows/linux systems - with some modifications) and provide identical docker-level environment - so you can easily set up and reuse you scripts/dockerfiles, and setup environment for new team member in very fast way (he just need to install docker and create similar folder-structure and get copy of scripts - thats all). I work this way for 2 year and with my team - and we are very happy

### Instruction

- Install docker using e.g. [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44346110/860099)
- Prepare 'special' directory for work e.g. my directory is `/Users/kamil/work` (I will use this directory further - but it can be arbitrary) - this directory will be 'interface' between docker containers and your mac file ststem. Inside this dir create following dir structure:

  `/Users/kamil/work/code` - here you put your projects with code

  `/Users/kamil/work/tools`

  `/Users/kamil/work/tools/docker-data` - here we map containers output data like logs (or database files if someone ouse db  etc.)

  `/Users/kamil/work/tools/docker`

  `/Users/kamil/work/tools/docker/node-cmd` - here we put docker node scripts
- inside `tools` create file `.env` which will contain in one place global-paths used in other scripts

  ```js
  toolspath="/Users/kamil/work/tools"
  codepath="/Users/kamil/work/code"
  workpath=/Users/kamil/work
  ```
- innside dir `../node-cmd` create file `dockerfile` with following content

  ```html
  # default  /var/www/html (mapped to .../code folder with projects)
  FROM node

  WORKDIR /work

  # Additional arbitrary tools (ng, gulp, bower)
  RUN npm install -g n @angular/cli bower gulp grunt

  CMD while true; do sleep 10000; done

  # below ports are arbitrary
  EXPOSE 3002 3003 3004 4200
  ```
- innside dir `../node-cmd` create file `run-container` with following content (this file should be executable e.g. by `chmod +x run-container`) - (notice how we map port-s and directories form external 'world' to internal docker filesystem)

  ```html
  set -e
  cd -- "$(dirname "$0")" # this script dir (not set on doubleclick)
  source ../../.env
  toolsdir=$toolspath/docker-data
  workdir=$workpath

  if [ ! "$(docker ps | grep node-cmd)" ] 
  then 
    docker build -t node-cmd .
    docker rm -f node-cmd |:
    docker run -d --name node-cmd -p 4200:4200 -p 4201:4201 -p 3002:3002 -p 3003:3003 -p 3004:3004 -v $toolsdir/node-cmd/logs:/root/.npm/_logs -v $workdir:/work node-cmd
  fi
  ```
- ok now you can add some project e.g. `work/code/myProject` and add to it following file 'run-cmd' (must be executable)

  ```js
  cd -- "$(dirname "$0")"
  ../../tools/docker/node-cmd/run-container
  docker exec -it node-cmd bash -c "cd /work/code/myProject; bash"
  ```
- then if you run above script (by double-click), you will see console with available node commands in project directory e.g. `npm install`
- to run project in background (e.g some serwice) e.g. run web-server angular-cli application you can use following script (named `run-front` -must be executable) - (you must also edit `/etc/hosts` file to add proper domain)

  ```js
  cd -- "$(dirname "$0")"
  open "http://my-angular.local:3002"
  ../../tools/docker/node-cmd/run-container
  docker exec -it node-cmd  /bin/sh -c "cd /work/code/my-angular-project; npm start"
  cat         # for block script and wait for user ctrl+C
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me [Fixing npm On Mac OS X for Homebrew Users](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689). And it does not require too many steps.

Just go to the solution part if you don't care about the why.

Here is the relevant part for convenience:

### Solution

This solution fixes the error caused by trying to run `npm update npm -g`. Once you're finished, you also won't need to use `sudo` to install npm modules globally.

Before you start, make a note of any globally installed npm packages. These instructions will have you remove all of those packages. After you're finished you'll need to re-install them.

Run the following commands to remove all existing global npm modules, uninstall node & npm, re-install node with the correct defaults, configure the location for global npm modules to be installed, and then install npm as its own package.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Node and npm should be correctly installed at this point. The final step is to add `~/.npm-packages/bin` to your `PATH` so npm and global npm packages are usable. To do this, add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
```

Now you can re-install any global npm packages you need without any problems.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm makes sense, I copied the relevant part.

Comment: After putting the following command I am getting the following error:
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
....npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bddev/.npm/_logs/2018-10-18T20_02_34_337Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: 1.535s@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bddev/.npm/_logs/2018-10-18T20_02_36_399Z-debug.log
It failed

Comment: There isn't a `--without-npm` option for `brew install node`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're unable to locate node just run `whereis node` and `whereis npm` and `whereis nvm` and you can remove the listed directories as needed.

You'll also need to entirely close your terminal and reopen it for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (Running Fedora 34).

**It was caused by using n: https://www.npmjs.com/package/n**

n helps you manage **different versions of node**, but it has it's own way to do that, it is not via the OSs package manager!

Thats why there were these unexpeted folders with node in it.

**This worked for me:**

1. reinstall node and npm.
2. reinstall n (sudo npm i -g n)
3. sudo n prune (removes all versions that are cached)
4. sudo n uninstall (removes the active version)
5. now you only have the expected version of node installed (the one installed in step 1)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using `n`, it will automatically reinstall npm when you change node versions. you can reverse `npm upgrade` damage by running the following commands:

1. `n` (select a different node version, npm will reinstall)
2. `n` (this time, select your preferred version)
3. `npm -v` (it will be an older version of NPM)
4. `npm install -g npm@7.x.x` (insert appropriate version)

Answer (score 1):

I was working on an angular project with many dependencies on Windows and was running Node 14.17.0. Suddenly I upgraded to the Node latest version 16.4.2 and started getting conflicts.

Rather than using --legacy-peer-deps all the time, I decided to downgrade.

1. Uninstalled Node from Control panel
2. Simply installed again Node 14 using Installer

and everything was fine again.

Comment: This is a temp fix, not a solution but anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On my end the issue was that I had both `nvm` and `volta` installed and where using different versions by default. I deleted volta as explained here: https://docs.volta.sh/advanced/uninstall and it worked fine

Answer (score -2):

If you had installed nvm via brew :

```
nvm unload shell

brew uninstall nvm
```

In case you still have `.nvm` in your root folder of mac, then manually remove it or do:

```
rm -rf $NVM_HOME
```

Also remove the below code from ~/.zshrc which you would have added manually while doing `brew install nvm`

```
  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score -8):

(server: ubuntu 14)

1.) install nvm (node version manager) https://github.com/creationix/nvm

2.) nvm install node

3.) npm -v 
(inquire npm version => 3.8.6)

4.) node -v
(inquire node version => v6.0.0)